# Use jQuery to change text on a link on first press, then go to link on second press

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery to make a "Are you sure?" function on a delete link.
My current code:

```
$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).removeClass("confirm-delete");
$(this).html("<i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i> Are you sure?");
$(this).attr("href", "?delete="+this.id.replace('id', ''));
});
```

I have given the link the class "confirm-delete" and it changes both the text and the url fine, but it will not let me press a second time. Nothing happens. I suspect it's because of the preventDefault, that's why I try to remove the class, but to no effect.
I hope someone can help me out with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by *unbinding the click event handler* right after the first run:

```
$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("confirm-delete");
    $(this).html("<i class='icon-remove icon-white'></i> Are you sure?");
    $(this).attr("href", "?delete="+this.id.replace('id', ''));

    // unbind
    $(this).off('click');
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure at this point, there is no need to remove the confirm-delete class.

Comment: I dont think its what he wants, read the title of the question.

Comment: @PedroEstrada - The above will do what he wants in the first click. On the second click it will proceed to the link (to the href that was set during first click) as there is no click event handler any more.

Comment: Thank you! Just the solution I needed.